# Getting svg fir image src with webpack returns 304

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, reactjs, webpack

I have a very strange situation . Here i will put the part of my code which will describe you the full problem.

```
const handleImageError = e => {
    e.target.onerror = null;
    e.target.src = 'factory1.svg';
};

<img src={`${data}?size=20`} onError={handleImageError} />
```

I am getting this kind of infinite loop `
[image]

The strange behaviour is when I change my icon to `factory2.svg` it works very well and loads the SVG file (200 OK).
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

would need to see more code but maybe try giving your ternary statement a way to break if it fails, looks like you only have a true statement..

```
img src={`${data} ? size=20: what to do if false here`}
```

could be possible that the image you put in that works is passing the condition and this one is not.